# How to read and decode fio --bandwidth-log?

Tags: logging, fio

I'm Looking for assistance with reading and decoding fio **--bandwidth-log.**

I've run the below command and the output includes a few columns as listed below, how to read and decode each column?

**fio --invalidate=1 --filename=/dev/nvme0n1 --direct=1 --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --time_based --runtime=3600 --bandwidth-log --name=/dev/nvme0n1 --rw=randread --bs=4k --log_avg_msec=1000**

Output example (first few lines):

501, 334730, 0, 0, 0

1177, 647294, 0, 0, 0

1678, 985860, 0, 0, 0

2180, 948023, 0, 0, 0

2681, 967369, 0, 0, 0

3182, 977405, 0, 0, 0

3683, 982035, 0, 0, 0

1. How to read the 1st column? No matter what period I provide for --timebased I get 1024 results in total.
2. The 2nd column doesn't fit IOPS, nor BW in MB/s. I read somewhere that it is in KB/s and tried conversion which provides reasonable MB/s in some cases but doesn't mix RW commands.

If I read the fio man page it is only mention the below with no explanation:

--bandwidth-log

Generate aggregate bandwidth logs.

Answer (score 1):

According to `fio(1)`, section `LOG FILE FORMATS` (latest version also available [online](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#log-file-formats)):

> Fio supports a variety of log file formats, for logging latencies, bandwidth, and IOPS. The logs share a common format, which looks like this:
>
> - *time (msec), value, data direction, block size (bytes), offset (bytes), command priority*
>
> *Time* for the log entry is always in milliseconds. The value logged depends on the type of log, it will be one of the following:
>
> - **Latency log**: Value is latency in nsecs
> - **Bandwidth log**: Value is in KiB/sec
> - **IOPS log**: Value is IOPS
>
> *Data direction* is one of the following:
>
> - 0: I/O is a READ
> - 1: I/O is a WRITE
> - 2: I/O is a TRIM

Note that, however, older versions of fio produces fewer fields. Always check the manual page shipped with *your* version of fio.

So your data should be interpreted, taking the first line for example:

> ```
> 501, 334730, 0, 0, 0
> ```
>
> - 501 ms since start of testing
> - 334,730 KiB/s measured for this duration
> - 0 = read operation
> - 0 (unable to determine from the current version of documentation)
> - 0 = command priority is normal